# set mountain time zone ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, time

The next link helps to stablish the time zone to US/Pacific-New

ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific-New /etc/localtime && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata

What could be the value(s) for Denver/Mountain time?

Comment: Have you looked in the directory you're already using, `/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/`? It contains `Mountain` as well as `Pacific-New` in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Well, given that I am using a docker container I did not even have the tzdata package so I had to install it using apt-get install tzdata and after that I selected US and Mountain. Thx